# Change progress bar text when completing 100%

Tags: python, progress-bar, rich

In this example the total progress is 5 seconds (I'm building a model that can be malleable, that I can use any amount of total seconds that will work the same):

```
from rich.progress import Progress
import time
import sys

def main(timeout):
    start_time = time.time()

    penultimate_quarter = timeout-1
    with Progress() as progress:
        task1 = progress.add_task("[green]Processing...", total=100)
        while not progress.finished:
            progress.update(task1, advance=100/penultimate_quarter)
            time.sleep(1)
        time.sleep(1)
        progress.update(task1, description="[blue]Complete Task", advance=100)

    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(5)
```

Output (same line):

[image]

But the output I wanted does not contain this `100%` with the message `Processing...`:

[image]

I tried to find a way to replace the `progress.finished` with a method that I could put in how many quarters of value have already been passed and pause the looping, something like:

```
penultimate_quarter = timeout-1
while progress.total_advance <= (penultimate_quarter/timeout):
    # rest of code...
```

How can I make this correctly and professionally according to [rich](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modification 1: Object value defining total progress

Before:

```
total=100
advance=100/penultimate_quarter
advance=100
```

After:

```
total=timeout
advance=timeout/penultimate_quarter
advance=timeout
```

Modification 2: position and use of `time.sleep`

Before:

```
penultimate_quarter = timeout-1
with Progress() as progress:
    task1 = progress.add_task("[green]Processing...", total=100)
    while not progress.finished:
        progress.update(task1, advance=100/penultimate_quarter)
        time.sleep(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    progress.update(task1, description="[blue]Complete Task", advance=100)
```

After:

```
penultimate_quarter = timeout-1
with Progress() as progress:
    task1 = progress.add_task("[green]Processing...", total=timeout)
    time.sleep(1)
    while not progress.finished:
        time.sleep(1)
        progress.update(task1, advance=timeout/penultimate_quarter)
    progress.update(task1, description="[blue]Complete Task", advance=timeout)
```

Final Code:

```
from rich.progress import Progress
import time
import sys

def main(timeout):
    start_time = time.time()

    penultimate_quarter = timeout-1
    with Progress() as progress:
        task1 = progress.add_task("[green]Processing...", total=timeout)
        time.sleep(1)
        while not progress.finished:
            time.sleep(1)
            progress.update(task1, advance=timeout/penultimate_quarter)
        progress.update(task1, description="[blue]Complete Task", advance=timeout)

    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(5)
```

Output (update same line):

[image]